# Separate server for video encoding?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ffmpeg, video-processing, video-encoding

I'm making a website that will handle video upload and encoding. My idea was to have the main server handle both client requests and video processing. But from my understanding, video encoding is cpu intensive. So I'm not sure if its a good idea to have one server do all the work, or have a separate server to do processing stuff. I want to try to future proof myself a bit in case I ever get high volumes of traffic, thus adding more processing work for the server.

So my question, is it overkill these days to have a separate server for video encoding, or am I going about this all wrong?

Ps. I'm using nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be overkill for someone starting out. As you mentioned, you don't have an idea of how much volume of traffic to expect yet, and it's difficult to project growth of your web app since it might grow gradually or take off immediately and hammer your server.

I would approach this in such a way where I can separate and queue the video processing work away from the main website. This will allow you to scale the video processing portion of your app without requiring you to run the entire website on there.

With a type of queuing system, you can also manage the amount of video you're processing at any point in time. So if 1 server can handle 5 video processing requests at once, any new request would have to wait until it finishes the previous request etc. Almost a micro-service type architecture.

Hope this gives you some ideas.